# Contraction of 4-dimensional epsilon tensor with four-vector components

Tags: tensor-calculus, feynman-diagrams

Evaluating a feynman diagram via the trace method I encoutered the term

$$
p_\alpha p'_\beta k_\mu k'_\nu\cdot \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}
$$
where $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ denotes the 4-dimensional epsilon tensor and the prefactors the four-momentum components of the particles involved in my 2->2 process. My question is how can I turn this term into a more convenient form?

Comment: "More convetional"? I think that this is as neat and as comprehensible as it gets....

Comment: That dot doesn’t belong there.

Comment: @mikestone : of course, it is not. This expression does not make any practical sense, it is fine only for theorists. The OP asked about the explicit form in terms of the scalar products of the 4-vectors.